# Embedding python in c segmentation fault

Tags: c, python-2.7

I'm making an executable from a bunch of .c files and I am having trouble embedding a python function in C. I can make the executable, but then I get segmentation fault when it runs and calls the function "send_from_python".

I have my python function in the file upload.py, which looks like

```
def send(a):
        return a + 1
```

Here's my attempt to call the python function from upload.py

```
int send_from_python(int a) {
    int res;
    PyObject *pModule, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    pModule = PyImport_Import(PyString_FromString((char*)"upload"));
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"send");

    pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyInt_FromLong(a));

    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

    res = PyInt_AsLong(pValue);

    return res; 
}
```

Whenever the executable calls the send_from_python function, I get segmentation fault

Here's the Makefile

```
GPU=0
CUDNN=0
OPENCV=0
OPENMP=0
DEBUG=0

ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
      -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
      -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
      -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]
#      -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] \ This one is deprecated?

# This is what I use, uncomment if you know your arch and want to specify
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52

VPATH=./src/:./examples
SLIB=libdarknet.so
ALIB=libdarknet.a
EXEC=darknet
OBJDIR=./obj/

CC=gcc
NVCC=nvcc
AR=ar
ARFLAGS=rcs
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread
COMMON= -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7/
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC

ifeq ($(OPENMP), 1)
CFLAGS+= -fopenmp
endif

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
OPTS=-O0 -g
endif

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

ifeq ($(OPENCV), 1)
COMMON+= -DOPENCV
CFLAGS+= -DOPENCV
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs opencv`
COMMON+= `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
endif

ifeq ($(GPU), 1)
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN), 1)
COMMON+= -DCUDNN
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN
LDFLAGS+= -lcudnn
endif

OBJ=gemm.o utils.o cuda.o deconvolutional_layer.o convolutional_layer.o list.o image.o activations.o im2col.o col2im.o blas.o crop_layer.o dropout_layer.o maxpool_layer.o softmax_layer.o data.o matrix.o network.o connected_layer.o cost_layer.o parser.o option_list.o detection_layer.o route_layer.o box.o normalization_layer.o avgpool_layer.o layer.o local_layer.o shortcut_layer.o activation_layer.o rnn_layer.o gru_layer.o crnn_layer.o demo.o batchnorm_layer.o region_layer.o reorg_layer.o tree.o  lstm_layer.o
EXECOBJA=captcha.o lsd.o super.o art.o tag.o cifar.o go.o rnn.o segmenter.o regressor.o classifier.o coco.o yolo.o detector.o nightmare.o attention.o darknet.o
ifeq ($(GPU), 1)
LDFLAGS+= -lstdc++
OBJ+=convolutional_kernels.o deconvolutional_kernels.o activation_kernels.o im2col_kernels.o col2im_kernels.o blas_kernels.o crop_layer_kernels.o dropout_layer_kernels.o maxpool_layer_kernels.o avgpool_layer_kernels.o
endif

EXECOBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(EXECOBJA))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
DEPS = $(wildcard src/*.h) Makefile include/darknet.h

CFLAGS+= `pkg-config --cflags python-2.7`
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs python-2.7`


#all: obj backup results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)
all: obj  results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)


$(EXEC): $(EXECOBJ) $(ALIB)
        $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(ALIB)

$(ALIB): $(OBJS)
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(SLIB): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
        $(NVCC) $(ARCH) $(COMMON) --compiler-options "$(CFLAGS)" -c $< -o $@

obj:
        mkdir -p obj
backup:
        mkdir -p backup
results:
        mkdir -p results

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJS) $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC) $(EXECOBJ)
```

I'm guessing the error has to do with the executable not being able to find upload.py, but I have no clue how to fix it. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some debugging traces after C-API calls (like `printf("pModule is %p\n", pModule);` after `PyImport_Import` call)?

Comment: The weird casts make me suspect that you compile this as C++, not C.

Comment: You need to add Py_Initialize() to be able to make the calls from with C.